# java client send Json as parameter or request body

Tags: java, json, servlets, httpclient

I would like to send a json string using httpost(apache). I have two ways to do it.
I can make it as a parameter like this :

```
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",myJsonString));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
```

or I can make it as request body:

```
StringEntity params =new StringEntity(myJsonString);
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.setEntity(params);
```

Which way I should do if myJsonString is very large? I'm using the 1st way because in servlet I just need to read it as a parameter.